# Sweeping past - meaning

Tags: meaning

An excerpt from *Tuesdays with Morrie*:

> On one particularly crazy day, a crush of reporters had tried to chase down Andre Agassi and his famous girlfriend, Brooke Shields, and I had gotten knocked over by a British photographer who barely muttered “Sorry” before **sweeping past**, his huge metal lenses strapped around his neck.

What does **sweeping past** mean?

Comment: **[sweep into/past/by etc.](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/sweep)** "4 [intransitive] to go somewhere quickly and confidently - **sweep into/past/by etc.**: *She swept into the office and announced she could only stay ten minutes.* 4a. [intransitive] to move quickly and smoothly without stopping for anyone or anything - **sweep past/through/along etc.**: *The limousine carrying the ambassador swept through the gates.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **sweep** in this figurative usage means to *move very quickly* and in some contexts *smoothly*, usually past someone or something. It's not very colloquial and most often seen in writing.

Note that both people and vehicles are capable of *sweeping*:

> He **swept** past me as if he didn't know me.
>
> The car **swept** past our house twice, as if the driver were trying to
>   see something, but not be seen.
>
> A jet **swept** over our heads, so close that it almost knocked us over.